# Java RNG check for duplicate

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

```
for(int i=0;i<maxNumbers;i++)
    {
        int r = rgen.nextInt(100) + 1;
        if(randomNumbers.contains(r))
                {

                    randomNumbers.remove(r);
                }
        s += r + ",";

        randomNumbers.add(String.valueOf(r));
    }
int index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();

            // check that selected item matches number generated
             if(index >= 0) 
                 {
                    // get selected item
                    String item = (String)jList1.getSelectedValue();

   // check if this item in number list
                    if(randomNumbers.contains(item))
                    {

                        randomNumbers.remove(item);
                    }
```

I am able to generate the 5 random numbers from an array list of 1-100, but I am unable to get the randomNumbers.remove(item) to prevent a duplicate entry. I added partial code to not make it super bulky. Any help or suggestions on how to not duplicate numbers?

Comment: Where and how is "item" defined?

Comment: i added item in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked to see if a number was in `randomeNumbers` *before* you added it, you wouldn't need to remove it.

Comment: I tried to check it this way but it didn't work 'code'    for(int i=0;i<maxNumbers;i++)
        {
            int r = rgen.nextInt(100) + 1;
            if(randomNumbers.contains(r))
                    {

                        randomNumbers.remove(r);
                    }
            s += r + ",";
            
            randomNumbers.add(String.valueOf(r));
        }

Comment: If `randomNumbers` contains `r`, you don't need to remove it just to add it again; leave `randomNumbers` alone, decrement `i` (since you didn't add a new number) and stay in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid duplicates:

```
for(int i=0;i<maxNumbers;i++)
{
    int r = rgen.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if(!randomNumbers.contains(r))
    {
        randomNumbers.add(String.valueOf(r));
        s += r + ",";
    }
}
```

But you might want to keep going until it's full:

```
int i=0;
while(i<maxNumbers)
{
    int r = rgen.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if(!randomNumbers.contains(r))
    {
        randomNumbers.add(String.valueOf(r));
        s += r + ",";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Not sure what you want to do with the jList exactly..

Answer (score 0):

In your code above it's not clear if you're tracking your numbers in a set or a list. You should track them in a set and just generate a random number until you find one that's not in your set. Once that's done do all the conversion/formatting necessary.

You could also pre-populate a list and then shuffle it, and finally take the first few.

In Java

```
public static List<Integer> randomNumbers(int n, int take) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c) {
        al.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    return al.subList(0, take);
}
```

Clojure

```
user=> (->> (range 1 101) shuffle (take 5))
(40 23 32 12 72)
```

It's not the most efficient method, but it will work just fine, and it's less error prone.